# split() method without csv

Tags: java, split

I need to split a text file into various fields.  I can control the way in which the values are divided however, since there are occasionally commas within each value, I can't use CSV.  What is the best way to go about importing the file?  Would TAB be a better delimiter?

The issue lies within Lippincott, Williams & Wilkins. That's all one field.

#### Example data

> History of Education Quarterly,1748-5959,na,Wiley-Blackwell, History of Political Economy,1527-1919,0018-2702,Duke University Press, History of Political Economy - Annual Supplement,na,missing, History Teacher,0018-2745,0018-2745,The Society for History Education, History Today,na,0018-2753,History Today Limited, Home Healthcare Nurse,na,0884-741X,Lippincott, Williams & Wilkins, Hospitality Law,na,0889-5414,LRP Publications, Hudson Review,na,0018-702X,Hudson Review Incorporated, Humanist - DC,na,0018-7399,American Humanist Associatioin, Idealistic Studies,na,0894-5373,F&W Media,

Comment: Please post an example of your input file.

Comment: Can you change the input?

Comment: How about [String#split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) ?

Comment: Yes, I think `TAB` would be fine, or pipe (`|`) if it's not in the text itself.

Comment: @eggHunter StackOverflow has a huge focus on editing your posts to make them better. I attempted to move your data into the post, but I probably didn't do it correctly. Please edit and fix.

Comment: I'm actually exporting from excel so I believe I can choose commas or tabs as separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hard coding a delimiter, why not just make it a configurable parameter, then if the input should ever change or something like that, you can easily adapt without having to rewrite.

If that's not an option, `TAB` or `|` seem like reasonable options without knowing what the input is

Comment: How do I delimite using a tab?  split.(\\t)?

Comment: @eggHunter exaclty like that.

Comment: It needs quotes around the \\t ("\\t") but that works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You choose any separator and it would break the day one of your data values have them. So, why not embrace a CSV library that would make sure the separators are escaped when required and read them back as well effortlessly.

Here's how you would do it with [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

```
 String[] values = {"one", "two,three", "four , five"};
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"));
 writer.writeNext(values);
 writer.close();

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] entries;
// reading just the first line
if ((entries = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println(entries[0] + ", " + entries[1] + ", " + entries[2]);
}
reader.close();
```

You could actually use any custom separator with OpenCSV like a Tab `\t` if you want.

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
```

But using CSVs makes your data files compatible with many other tools as well. So, it entirely depends on your compatibility requirements for your data files if any.

Comment: +1 always use a dedicated parser rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @eggHunter Sorry, but how do I help when you aren't using my proposed solution? You're still trying to read and split the file through String API. If you meant this as a response to Tim you need to comment on his answer.